# Take grep value and output the count and the value together

Tags: shell-script, grep

I am trying to make a bash script that greps value and output the count and the value together

Something like this

```
grep -c 'Thenis' example.txt > example.lst
```

But in that list file not only to show the count but also the value I have entered like this

```
Thenis: 123
```

Answer (score 5):

You can start a sub shell and use `$0` variable to do this.

```
bash -c 'echo "$0: $(grep -c $0 example.txt)"' 'Thenis' > example.lst
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `grep -c` prints only the number, we need to prefix with the given pattern.  This can be accomplished by using the shell builtin `printf` to print the pattern without a following newline.  Then we let grep print the count (on the same line).

Using parenthesis to place both statements in a sub-shell allows all of the output to be redirected only once.

I would do it like this:

```
(printf '%s: ' Thenis; grep -c Thenis example.txt) > example.lst
```

If you wanted to make a simple script to do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]
then
    echo >&2 "Usage: $0 pattern file"
    exit 1
fi
printf '%s: ' "$1"
grep -c "$1" "$2"
```

Answer (score 1):

No one tried to use sed yet?

```
grep -c Thenis example.txt|sed s/^/Thenis:\ /  > example.lst
```

or if you want a more versatile solution and have gnu sed

```
echo Thenis -- example.txt | \
sed -re 's/^(.*) -- (.*)$/echo -n \1:;grep -c \1 \2/e'
```

a word of warning on that last one: powerful enough to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate this with variables. Also you can embed the command's output with the character `

In the line below, change `outputFile=/dev/stdout` to your own value,

```
string='Thenis'; inputFile=example.txt; outputFile=/dev/stdout;  echo "${string}: `grep -c ${string} ${inputFile}`" > ${outputFile}
```

Or in different lines

```
string='Thenis'  
inputFile=example.txt  
outputFile=/dev/stdout 
echo "${string}: `grep -c ${string} ${inputFile}`" > ${outputFile}
```

Also, for the quotes you can use either ' or ". For the variables either $var of ${var}, as you prefer.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Try writing `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1: $(grep -c "$1" "$2")
```

So if `example.txt`:

```
Then is, Then-is, Then's, Thenis, Thins,
Thesis, Thanes, Thence, Things,
Thenis, Thorns, Thane's
```

Run `script.sh` in your command prompt, saving its output to `example.lst`:

```
$ ./script.sh 'Thenis' example.txt > example.lst
```

The desired `searchword: count` result can then be found in `example.lst`:

```
$ cat example.lst
Thenis: 2
```

### Details

- as with all scripts, ensure script is executable for example by issuing the command `sudo chmod +x script.sh`
- bash positional parameters: `$1` for the first argument passed to the `script.sh`, `$2` for the second, and so on
- `$(` ... `)` is command substitution to get the results of the commands contained, out for use by the `echo`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` instead. It is much more flexible.

E.g. to emulate `grep -c` you can use:

```
awk '/Thenis/{total+=1}END{print "Thenis: ",total}'
```

Though please note, that in this case (this applies to `grep` as well) only lines with word Thenis are counted. It is not count of the word Thenis.
In case you need to count number of Thenis words in file you can use following `awk` construction:

```
awk '/Thenis/{total+=gsub("Thenis","")}END{print "Thenis: ",total}
```

or the way with variables (to type Thenis only once)

```
awk -v word="Thenis" '$0 ~ word{total+=gsub(word,"")}END{print word,": ",total}
```